# Error in multiple Unit Test being tested at once

Tags: unit-testing, mvvm, kotlin, android-room

In the following project

https://github.com/Crash1hd/MultipleTestTesting

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal connection pointer 1. Current pointers for thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#3,5,SDK 28] []

    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.getConnection(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:367)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.prepareStatement(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:416)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:89)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:562)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:323)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:298)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:549)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:460)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:69)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:277)
    at com.mycomp.roomwordsample.data.db.WordDao_Impl.deleteAll(WordDao_Impl.java:81)
    at com.mycomp.roomwordsample.data.db.WordRepository$deleteAllLogsOlderThan$2.invokeSuspend(WordRepository.kt:28)
    at |b|b|b(Coroutine boundary.|b(|b)
    at com.mycomp.roomwordsample.ui.WordViewModel$deleteAllLogsOlderThanA$1.invokeSuspend(WordViewModel.kt:36)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal connection pointer 1. Current pointers for thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#3,5,SDK 28] []
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.getConnection(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:367)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.prepareStatement(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:416)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:89)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:562)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:323)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:298)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:549)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:460)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:69)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:277)
    at com.mycomp.roomwordsample.data.db.WordDao_Impl.deleteAll(WordDao_Impl.java:81)
    at com.mycomp.roomwordsample.data.db.WordRepository$deleteAllLogsOlderThan$2.invokeSuspend(WordRepository.kt:28)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

When I run this set of tests
https://github.com/Crash1hd/MultipleTestTesting/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/mycomp/roomwordsample/WordDaoTestA.kt

It seems to have to do with the function that I am calling in initializationLogging in WordApplication
https://github.com/Crash1hd/MultipleTestTesting/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mycomp/roomwordsample/WordApplication.kt

Commenting out LogA.purgeOldLogsGreaterThan(7) this line all the tests pass.

I am at a loss as to why it is failing? each test is exactly the same and they all work (just not all at once).

I am wondering if it has to do with how I am calling the WordViewModel in application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I came across this blog post

https://artemzin.com/blog/how-to-mock-dependencies-in-unit-integration-and-functional-tests-dagger-robolectric-instrumentation/

and in the comments, there is this comment by Krzysiek Bielicki

You can just create Application class prefixed with 'Test'. Robolectric will automatically use it as Application for all tests.

So I tried that created class TestWordApplication added everything that was in WordApplication (but excluded the call to initializationLogging() and now all the test pass as its no longer trying to access and purge the actual database.

I found this also on the Robolectric website confirming 
http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/

Thanks.  and a very special thank you to Krzysiek Bielicki (whomever you are) as you just made my night :)